# Android Ormlite - Building queries with conditional where clause

Tags: android, sql, hibernate, orm, ormlite

At first please take a look at the code below. I have used various ORM (Hibernate, DataMapper) before but here in ORMLite I am facing a very teasing problem. Look in my code I am gonna set where clause which is conditional. According to ormlite api and() method should be placed in the middle of two where clause. In my case there remains an extra and() method which is not allowed in ORMLite.

So What is the best solution in this case ?

```
if(filter.getInstituionId() != null)
    builder.where().eq(BuyPostItem.FIELD_INSTITUTION_ID, filter.getInstituionId()).and();
if(filter.getBookCategoryId() != null)
    builder.where().eq(BuyPostItem.FIELD_CATEGORY_ID, filter.getBookCategoryId()).and();
if(filter.getMinPrice() != null)
    builder.where().ge(BuyPostItem.FIELD_EXPECTED_PRICE, filter.getMinPrice()).and();
if(filter.getMaxPrice() != null)
    builder.where().le(BuyPostItem.FIELD_EXPECTED_PRICE, filter.getMaxPrice()).and();
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used `ORMLite` by myself, but I think you could do like this

```
Where where = builder.where();

// dirty hack
boolean hasAnythingBeforeThis = false;

if(filter.getInstituionId() != null) {
    where.eq(BuyPostItem.FIELD_INSTITUTION_ID, filter.getInstituionId());
    hasAnythingBeforeThis = true;
}
if(filter.getBookCategoryId() != null) {
    if(hasAnythingBeforeThis){
        where.and();
    }
    where.eq(BuyPostItem.FIELD_CATEGORY_ID, filter.getBookCategoryId());
    hasAnythingBeforeThis = true;
}
if(filter.getMinPrice() != null) {
    if(hasAnythingBeforeThis){
        where.and();
    }
    where.ge(BuyPostItem.FIELD_EXPECTED_PRICE, filter.getMinPrice());
    hasAnythingBeforeThis = true;
}
if(filter.getMaxPrice() != null) {
    if(hasAnythingBeforeThis){
        where.and();
    }
    where.le(BuyPostItem.FIELD_EXPECTED_PRICE, filter.getMaxPrice());
    hasAnythingBeforeThis = true;
}
```

You can find out more [in docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html)

Comment: what if first IF statement is not execute ? then where clause gets a and() first. do you understand ?

Comment: @mahbub.kuet, missed that part. Modified the code, but there will be a more elegant solution that what I've posted. I'll edit if i get a better idea.